# Troca de chaves Diffie-Hellman em grupo

Tags: criptografia

Como fazer uma troca de chaves diffie hellman com 10-20 pessoas por exemplo, tem como?

Comment: Aparentemente esse é um problema ainda em aberto, mas [há estudos/propostas](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=multi+party+diffie+hellman&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=7efoVLrmDKqKsQSxkoHIDQ) para realizar essa extensão [de 2 para N participantes]. Não posso falar nada quanto à solidez dessas propostas, entretanto...

Comment: P.S. [Essa pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5648902/520779) parece sugerir que a ausência de protocolos nesse sentido é em parte devido à pouca necessidade prática do mesmo - uma vez que Alice estabeleceu um canal seguro de comunicação com Bob, e Bob outro com Charlie, Bob pode criar um novo segredo (i.e. uma nova chave) e compartilhá-lo tanto com Alice quanto com Charlie. Estes podem então se comunicar diretamente - sem envolver Bob - usando esse segredo. Se Dave faz DH então com qualquer um deles, Dave pode receber também o segredo e se comunicar com todos os outros. Etc.

Answer (score 3):

Esse é um problema em aberto. Enquanto fazer com dois participantes é trivial, e com três possível (embora envolva uma matemática um pouco mais avançada), não se conhece um meio de se fazer isso para quatro ou mais participantes.

## Dois participantes, generalizado

As operações do [Diffie-Hellman](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie-Hellman) são feitas não no conjunto dos números Naturais, Inteiros, Reais, etc, mas sim em um [grupo cíclico](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grupo_c%C3%ADclico) com [gerador](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunto_gerador_de_um_grupo) `g`. Suponha que Alice, Bob, Charlie e Dave publiquem cada um seu componente público no protocolo:

> A = g<sup>a</sup>, B = g<sup>b</sup>, C = g<sup>c</sup>, D = g<sup>d</sup>

Como `a`, `b`, `c` e `d` são mantidos em segredo, os demais participantes não podem usá-lo em qualquer cálculo. Para Alice e Bob criarem uma chave comum, ambos precisam calcular:

> Kab = g<sup>a*b</sup>

O que é simples: Alice conhece `a` e `B = g^b`, então basta ela fazer `B^a = (g^b)^a = g^(a*b) = Kab`. Bob conhece `b` e `A = g^a`, então `A^b = (g^a)^b = g^(a*b) = Kab`. Mas e se os quatro participantes quiserem criar uma chave comum? Um candidato natural seria:

> Kabcd = g<sup>a*b*c*d</sup>

Mas aí temos um problema: Alice só conhece `a`, `B = g^b`, `C = g^c` e `D = g^d`; ela não conhece `b`, `c` e `d`, nem possui meios de obtê-los (se possuísse, o DH seria totalmente inseguro, pois o atacante também conseguiria calcular esses valores com base em `A`, `B`, `C` e `D`).

A única maneira de calcular isso seria com ajuda dos demais participantes:

1. Alice calcula `Kab = B^a`, `Kac = C^a` e `Kad = D^a`; ela **envia** `Kac` para Bob (publicamente, ou privadamente com ajuda de `Kab`);
2. Bob agora conhece `Kac = g^(a*c)`, e pode calcular `Kabc = Kac ^ b = (g^(a*c))^b = g^(a*b*c)`; ele envia isso pra Dave;
3. Dave agora conhece `Kabc = g^(a*b*c)`, e pode calcular `Kabcd = Kabc^d = (g^(a*b*c))^d = g^(a*b*c*d)`.

Etc. Se cada participante enviar aos outros os resultados intermediários, no fim todos poderão calcular a chave comum.

O problema é: não é um desperdício de troca de mensagens? Ora, se for pra cada participante sair revelando parte da computação pros outros, de modo que todos possam calcular o resultado final, não seria mais simples em vez disso:

1. Alice calcula `Kab = B^a`, `Kac = C^a` e `Kad = D^a`;
2. Alice cria uma nova chave `K` aleatória;
3. Alice **envia** `K` para cada um dos outros, usando `Kab`, `Kac` e `Kad`.

A suposta vantagem do Diffie-Hellman em grupo seria cada participante publicar sua "chave pública" apenas uma vez, e qualquer participante poder calcular uma chave comum ao grupo inteiro sem nenhuma troca adicional de mensagem. De modo que esse esquema não seria uma solução para o problema proposto.

## Três participantes

Com apenas três participantes, é possível fazer isso sem nenhuma troca adicional de mensagens, mas é necessário se estabelecer alguns parâmetros adicionais, e a forma de cálculo é um tanto mais complexa. A matemática envolvida está além do meu alcance, mas uma explicação da técnica pode ser vista [nessa resposta no crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1034).

Em resumo, é descrita uma operação `e(P, Q)` tal que `e(P^a, Q^b) = e(P, Q)^(a*b)`, de modo que se Alice, Bob e Charlie publicarem:

> A = g<sup>a</sup>, B = g<sup>b</sup>, C = g<sup>c</sup>

Então Alice pode calcular:

```
Kabc = e(B, C)^a = e(g^b, g^c)^a = (e(g, g)^(b*c))^a = e(g, g)^(a*b*c)
```

Bob pode calcular:

```
Kabc = e(A, C)^b = e(g^a, g^c)^b = (e(g, g)^(a*c))^b = e(g, g)^(a*b*c)
```

e Charlie pode calcular:

```
Kabc = e(A, B)^c = e(g^a, g^b)^c = (e(g, g)^(a*b))^c = e(g, g)^(a*b*c)
```

Nota: em alguns cenários, o passo "confirmação de chaves" (i.e. cada participante provar aos demais que ele computou a chave correta, que um adversário não interferiu no processo) pode ser necessário, tal como no DH de dois participantes. Nesse caso, os benefícios dessa técnica se anulam (já que trocas adicionais de mensagens são necessárias), sendo mais uma razão pela qual isso é pouco usado na prática.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade existem várias propostas de acordos de chaves em grupo. Claro que é tudo muito acadêmico então não há padrões ou produtos pronto, mas os protocolos existem.

Alguns são bem complicados, o mais simples que achei foi esse, [aqui está arquivo do paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4cMWuEOLVUHY2l2dDVJTnJDR3c/view?usp=sharing).

É um short paper publicado no IEEE communication letters,ele é bem claro na descrição do protocolo, então acho que você não vai ter problemas pra entender.

Qualquer dúvida na notação, ou mesmo na parte matemática é só perguntar. ;)